# Google drive "invalid credentials for email@gmail.com"

Tags: gnome, cloud, google

I tried to access my google drive on ubuntu, but I get the subject error message. I mounted the drive through gnome control center as seen in these instructions: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-google-drive-ubuntu-16-04-linux-desktops.

I tried to go into online accounts and log into my google account, which I succesfully did, but no difference in being able to access drive. Please help thanks.

Comment: This could be a browser issue. Have you tried a different browser? Try installing  chromium - - `sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser` and log in.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to access it via the browser, it's installed on my computer through the gui, I can't remember how. It shows up kind of like another drive except it looks like a server instead of a drive.

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide more info on what software you're using and how you're using it if you want to attract any quality answers. I suggest adding more info to your question.

Comment: I used these instructions, so it is gnome control center I guess: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-google-drive-ubuntu-16-04-linux-desktops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work, I had to restart my computer then go to online accounts and login again. I think this may have happened because I hadnt been on ubuntu in a while

Comment: can you tell me what address do you yous to access google-drive (i found many tutorials, but there is no info about address - actually prefix:
XX://email@gmail.com   (i need XX)

Answer (score 7):

update your credentials for online accounts by going to System Settings(top right corner of monitor), then Online Accounts in the left column. this fixed the same error message i had when i clicked on my google drive from my Files app. hope this helps someone.

Comment: credentials have *expired*??? this is too annoying, how can i prevent them from expiring???

Comment: ok so why isn't it working?  after i sign in with the correct user name and password (just confirmed in an incognito window)  and tell it to "Allow" all the access it requests, it drops me back at the "Google Account" dialog with no change, "Credentials have expired"!