# Cannot access network drive after changing password

Tags: 16.04, networking, password, samba

This is a ridiculous issue. I can remember I was facing the same issue a while ago but I forgot how I was able to fix it.

I had to change my domain password. As I try to access a network location (samba), all I get is

> **Oops! Something went wrong.**
>  Don't have permission to access the requested location.

But I know I have the permission and I know it's just because I had to change the password and it's just not capable of asking for the new one.

How can I make it forget the password so I can access my data?

Comment: Need more info please. Are you logging into a network share via a web browser? Are you using something that has saved your passwords? Any additional specific info would help.

Comment: I want to access a network drive using samba.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon these post since I had the same problem with my google drive account. This post solved the situation: [Google drive "invalid credentials for email@gmail.com"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890324/google-drive-invalid-credentials-for-emailgmail-com?newreg=5ac3b34af6a845f2ab9fb804898ae148)

Comment: Could you please post the actual steps to solve the problem (in case that link breaks, in which case your answer would no longer be helpful)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the previous password in "Passwords and Keys" (also known as seahorse).